# Pandas groupby and transpose related problem

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I am working on a pandas data frame. Facing a problem related to group by operation. My data frame is -

```
Name    A          Job       B
A      Online      Govt      22
B      Offline     Pvt       50
C      Others      Other     33
A      Others      Govt      62
B      Online      Pvt       18
C      Offline     Other     35
A      Offline     Govt      53
B      Online      Pvt       75
C      Others      Other     74
```

My final output should be -

```
Name   Offline    Online   Others   Govt   Pvt  Other
A       53        20        62        1      0    0
B       50        18        75        0      1    0
C       35        74        33        0      0    1
```

I have done the following code -

```
data = pd.read_csv('/Users../pandas_data/abc1.csv')
df3 = data.groupby(['Name', 'A'])['B']\
   .first()\
   .unstack(fill_value='NA')\
   .rename_axis(None, 1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at pandas' [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), for the second part of the output you can use

```
pd.pivot_table(
    data=df.drop(columns='A'),
    index=['Name'],
    columns=['Job'],
    aggfunc=lambda x: int(len(x) > 0),
    fill_value=0
)
```

which would yield

```
        B          
Job  Govt Other Pvt
Name               
A       1     0   0
B       0     0   1
C       0     1   0
```

then do something similar for the first part (don't know how to interpret `..`), like

```
pd.pivot_table(
    data=df.drop(columns='Job'),
    index=['Name'],
    columns=['A'],
    aggfunc= # depends on what you expect
)
```

and finally concatenate using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes) over `axis=1`.

Comment: @vizana - Sorry for that..you are not understand '..'. I have just edited the '..' portion.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the first part with pivot(),
and the second part with get_dummies(), and then concatenate them into one data frame as follows:

```
part1 = df.pivot(index="Name",columns="A",values="B")
part2 = df.groupby(["Name"])["Job"].first().str.get_dummies()
ans = pd.concat([part1, part2], axis=1)
```